# Windows Batch for Pipe out Variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, pipeline

How can i get the value to `myVar` attribute to use in the other part of code.

```
set myVar =
ECHO "httpsxxxxxx_cmidxxxxx_2014-04-12_14-54-53_abc3654.xml" | find /i "2014-04-12" | (set /p myVar= & set myVar)
ECHO myvar "%myVar%" /**** This is empty String**********/
```

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to get? Extract someting from the xml file, is it just a proof of concept, .... ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you are asking is:

This line

```
echo "someValue" | find /i "Value" | (set /p myVar= & set myVar)
```

will show you the variable has been set. `echo` command send its output to `find` command, and the output of it is piped into the `set /p`, assigning the value to the variable, value that the `set` will show in console.

Then the following line

```
echo myvar "%myVar%"
```

shows no data. Why?

When `cmd` finds a pipe definition, with data flowing from one program to other, each of the elements in the pipe is a separate process with its own **copy** of the environment block of the parent process (where the batch file is running), so the `set /p myVar= & set myVar` is not running inside the same instance as the batch file. The variable is set in another process, and as the changes are made in a copy of the environment, they are not visible from the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('ECHO "httpsxxxxxx_cmidxxxxx_2014-04-12_14-54-53_abc3654.xml" ^| find /i "2014-04-12"') do set MyVar=%%a

echo %MyVar%
```

I don't anderstand what you are trying to do.

But assuming that you're looking for a `.xml` file who contain the string `"2014-04-12"` in a directory. The code will be :

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b/a-d *.xml ^| find /i "2014-04-12"') do set MyVar=%%a
```

Answer (score 0):

Annotating your code:

```
1: set myVar =
2: ECHO "httpsxxxxxx_cmidxxxxx_2014-04-12_14-54-53_abc3654.xml" | find /i "2014-04-12" | (set /p myVar= & set myVar)
3: ECHO myvar "%myVar%" /**** This is empty String**********/
```

On line 1:, there is a space between `myVar` and `=`. This is incorrect. CMD.EXE considers that there is a variable called `"myVar "`. Change this to `"myVar"`.
On line 2:, I guess that you intended to use `TYPE` to output the file "httpsxxxxxx_cmidxxxxx_2014-04-12_14-54-53_abc3654.xml". In any case you could have written this, instead:

```
FIND /I "2014-04-12" httpsxxxxxx_cmidxxxxx_2014-04-12_14-54-53_abc3654.xml
```